# How do I connect mysql with cypress through ssh tunneling?

Tags: mysql, node.js, cypress, ssh-tunnel

Currently cypress supports mysql connection without using ssh as seen in the link below

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Allows-a-single-argument-only

But I am trying to connect cypress to mysql through an ssh tunneling.
I am using the npm package `mysql-ssh` to establish the connection.

I am able to achieve this directly using `node.js` but I am facing issues while implementing through cypress. Here's the snippet I tried in `node.js`.

```
const mysqlssh = require('mysql-ssh');
const fs = require('fs');

mysqlssh.connect(
    {
        host: 'x.x.x.x',
        user: 'xyz',
        privateKey: fs.readFileSync('filePath')  //this is the ssh filePath
    },
    {
        host: 'HOST_NAME',
        user: 'USER_NAME',
        password: 'xxxx',
        database: 'DB_NAME'
    }
)
.then(client => {
    client.query('select * from TABLE_NAME',  function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(results);
        mysqlssh.close()
    })
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

I want to do this either through the `cypress/plugins/index.js` file or directly in `cypress/integration`. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution. Here is my code for `cypress/plugins/index.js` file:

```
const dotenvPlugin = require('cypress-dotenv');
const mysqlssh = require('mysql-ssh');
const fs = require('fs');

module.exports = (on, config) => {
  //  `config` is the resolved Cypress config
    config = dotenvPlugin(config);

    on('task', {
        executeSql (sql, ...args) {
            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                try {
                    let connection = await mysqlssh.connect(  {
                            host: process.env.SSH_HOST,
                            user: process.env.SSH_USER,
                            privateKey: fs.readFileSync(process.env.HOME + '/.ssh/id_rsa_old')
                        },
                        {
                            host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
                            user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
                            password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
                            database: process.env.MYSQL_DB
                        });
                    let result = await connection.promise().query(sql, args);
                    mysqlssh.close();
                    resolve(result[0][0]); 
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }
            });
        }
    })

    return config
}
```

So this connection has to be established in this file b/c cypress does not communicate with node process supplied by the host. So we need to use cypress tasks to run a Node code. see docs here - https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task#Examples

And in a test file example, I used it like so:

```
describe('Db Test',  () => {
    it('Query Test', () => {
        cy.task('executeSql', 'SELECT count(id) as cnt FROM table_name').then(result => {
            expect(result.cnt, 'Does not equal to 8').to.equal(2000);
        })
    })
})
```

P.S. Additional `cypress-dotenv` package is just used to load env vars from .env file.